# C - Accessing data AFTER memory has been free()ed?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm reading a lot about malloc() and free() in Standard C.  As I understand it, you `malloc()` for some memory exactly once and then you `free()` that same memory exactly once.  It may be bad practice, but I understand that after you `malloc()` memory, you can define multiple pointers to it.  And once you `free()` any of those pointers, the allocated memory is de-allocated?

Consider this toy example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    char* p = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));     // allocate memory
    int* q = (int*)p;                               // pointer to the same block of memory
    *p = 'A';                                       // Input some data
    printf("TEST::  %c %d\n", *p, *q);              // Everything's ok so far...
    free(p);                                        // free() my allocated memory?
    sleep(10);                                      // wait
    printf("%c\n", *q);                             // q now points to de-allocated memory
                                                    // shouldn't this segfault?

    free(q);                                        // *** SEGFAULTS HERE ***

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
[Linux]$ ./a.out
TEST::  A 65

*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001ac4010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
...lots of backtrack info...
```

So I assume that when I `free()` the first pointer, the memory is considered `free()`ed, but the ***data value(s)*** I wrote in this block of memory are still "there", which is why I can access them via the second pointer?

(I'm not proposing that this is a good idea, I'm trying to understand the logic of the system.)

Comment: That's called ["Undefined Behavior"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Sometimes it seems to work. Other times things go poorly. But, no you should not access memory after `free()` it.

Comment: There's no segfault in your code right now. The error message is from your C library detecting corrupted internal structures.

Comment: Even the *use* of the pointer itself after `free` has undefined behaviour, i.e. you may not even compare it to `NULL`.

Comment: btw, size of char is 1, because sizeof returns the size of the given type in *chars*.

Comment: Before asking this question, you should have typed 'access data after free' in both google and SO.  They you wouldn't have had to ask the question here.

Comment: Often you need several pointers to the same buffer. What's important is to designate one as the "owning" pointer , and to free that pointer as you invalidate all the rest. (Often the owning pointer is root of a tree, whilst other nodes have back pointers to the root, when you destroy the tree, you destroy all the nodes in one operation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you malloc memory, you're given a pointer to some space, and when you free it, you're giving it back to the system. Often, you can still access this memory, but using memory after you have freed it is VERY BAD.

The exact behavior is undefined, but on most systems you can either continue to access the memory, or you get a segfault.

One interesting experiment you can try is to try and malloc more memory after you free'd that pointer. On most systems I've tried, you get the same block back (which is a problem, if you were relying on the data being there in the freed block). Your program would end up using both pointers, but since they point to the same physical data, you'll be overwriting your own data!

The reason for this is that when you malloc data (depending on the malloc implementation of course), malloc first requests a block of data from the operating system (typically much larger than the malloc request), and malloc will give you a segment of that memory. You'll be able to access any part of the memory malloc originally got from the operating system though, since to the operating system, it's all memory your program is internally using. When you make a free, you're telling the malloc system that the memory is free, and can be given back to the program later on.

Writing outside of the malloc area is very dangerous because

1. It can segfault, depending on your c implementation
2. You can overwrite metadata structures malloc is relying on, which causes VERY BAD PROBLEMS when you free/malloc more data later on

If you are interested in learning more, I would recommend running your program through valgrind, a leak detector, to get a better picture of what's freed/not freed.

PS: On systems without an OS, you most likely wont get a segfault at all, and you'll be able to wite anywhere willy nilly. The OS is responsible for triggering a segfault (when you write/read to memory you don't have access to, like kernel or protected memory)

If you are interested in learning more, you should try to write your own malloc, and/or read/learn about the memory management operating systems do.

Comment: It is also possible that some secure OSes might actually zero the memory that was freed. Just in case.

Answer (score 2):

The crash in your code is due to double `free`. [Appendix J.2 of C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) says that behaviour is undefined for example when:

> The pointer argument to the free or realloc function does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc (7.22.3.3, 7.22.3.5).

However it is possible to write code that will crash on Linux just by reading a value from memory that was just freed.

In glibc + Linux there are two different mechanisms of memory allocations. One uses the `brk`/`sbrk` to resize the data segment, and the other uses the `mmap` system call to ask the operating system to give large chunks of memory. The former is used for small allocations, like your 10 characters above, and `mmap` for large chunks. So you might get a crash by even accessing the memory just after free:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* p = malloc(1024 * 1024);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    free(p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

And finally, the C11 standard says that the behaviour is undefined even when

> The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function is used (7.22.3).

This means that after not only that *dereferencing the pointer* (`*p`) has *undefined behaviour*, but also that it is not safe to *use* the pointer in any other way, even doing `p == NULL` has *UB*. This follows from [C11 6.2.4p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2) that says:

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.