# freed allocated memory still accessable

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm freeing a variable I allocated using malloc, but after I've freed it I try to access it and it still works fine.

I would expect a segmentation fault when accessing this memory but I dont get one.

Here is a simple example to show the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 2;
    arr[4]=9;
    free(arr);
    printf("%d\n",arr[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 9.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of *undefined behavior*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C - Accessing data AFTER memory has been free()ed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588482/c-accessing-data-after-memory-has-been-freeed)

Comment: It's your responsibility as 4he programmer to not write bad or invalid code. Like attempting to use memory not belonging to your process.

Comment: Freeing the memory does not imply it is made inaccessible. There is no such (hardware) mechanism required by the C standard. The memory still exists, it only is not yours anymore and can be reused at any time.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794). It's not quite the same question but the explanation still applys very well to your question. Just replace _"How can it be? Isn't the memory of a local variable inaccessible outside its function?"_ with _"How can it be? Isn't the memory inaccessible once it has been freed with the `free` function?"_

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say, the problem seems to be that you **expect** a segmentation fault.

The C language standard doesn't **require** a segmentation fault. Once you access a freed pointer **anything can happen** - including nothing.

Most likely, the memory allocator **cached** the memory for re-use instead of returning the memory to the system. This way, in case you would need to allocate memory again, the second allocation would be faster.

This means that, from a **system's** point of view, your program still "owns" that memory.

From an **allocator's** point of view, that memory is owned by the allocator and you shouldn't use it (the allocator might write its own data over there).

From your **program's** point of view you have a **quite** bug.